# Webform update!

Tags: webforms

I need to update webform module in my live site, I noticed the warning with doing that with the user Interface so I want to update the files manually, ( because we don't use drush ), Can I get directions for doing this update? again since the site is live and this is our first Drupal site I want to make sure from not breaking the site or having any issues!

also, I have the files in Cpanel so from where exactly should I start to upload the updated files?
is it like in the screenshot below
[image]

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: What does the warning say when trying the update with the administrative interface?

Comment: "The Webform module may not update properly using this administrative interface. It is strongly recommended that you update the Webform module manually or by using Drush."  This is exactly what showing when trying the update with the administrative interface?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much more to say than what is explained in the Drupal doc when you click on the links available in the warning (See [Updating a Module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/security-update-module.html))

Whatever the method you use for updating your module, I advise you to always test your update on a copy of your website (local environment, development server... with at least similar php version) to ensure everything works fine before updating the live website.

Regarding the update process:

- if you manage your modules with Composer,

  - on the copy of your website, open a console,
  - go to the root of your website (same level as the composer.json file),
  - run `composer update drupal/webform --with-dependencies`,
  - run the database update script (yoursite.com/update.php).
  - If everything is okay, copy the composer.lock file to your prod environment,
  - open a console on your prod environment,
  - go to the root of your website and run `composer install` (it will update your packages and modules to the versions specified in the composer.lock file).
  - finally, run the database update script and check that your website works fine.
- if you don't use Composer, follow the steps from the Drupal doc [11.6. Manually Downloading Module or Theme Files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/extend-manual-install.html). First for the copy of your website and then for your prod website.